# Cordova / Phonegap IOS Persistent Storage

Tags: ios, cordova

I am in the process of creating an iOS 8 app through Cordova. I have a backend DB with its own sessions etc. But several features of the app happen locally.

My question is what is the most persistent way of storing information on the device itself. I have seen several postings on localStorage and through the local openDatabase but I was curious what opinions are on the most efficient way of storing something locally without the OS cleaning up any of the cache / storage info and how long that data will last, or if this is even plausible.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Cordova documentation page on storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)?

Comment: I have, my question is how long each lasts and how they are cleared out.

Comment: The storage options you mentioned are persistent through out the life time of the application installed. You can use core data (if you have basic knowledge of core data)with PhoneGap by writing a pluign interface. There is no restriction to the data saved and querying is also easy with that plugin.